# How to fetch data from url with changing key in Dart?

Tags: database, flutter, dart, web-crawler

I want to fetch the Artificial brightness data from this Website: https://www.lightpollutionmap.info/  in Dart.
If you click on the map it sends a get request to another url that looks something like this:
https://www.lightpollutionmap.info/QueryRaster/?qk=MTY3MTk1Nzk2NjUwNztpc3Vja2RpY2tzOik=&ql=wa_2015&qt=point&qd=14.850636168450944,50.09611381452743 
My question is, how can I get the qk part, it seems to be different every time you click on the map?

My Code currently looks like this:

```
Future initiate() async {
  var client = Client();
  Response response = await client.get(
      "https://www.lightpollutionmap.info/QueryRaster/?qk=MTY3MTk1Nzk2NjUwNztpc3Vja2RpY2tzOik=&ql=wa_2015&qt=point&qd=14.850636168450944,50.09611381452743");

  print(response.body.toString());
 }
```

Comment: you can't - `qk` is a protection key to prevent unauthorized usage of their api - if you want you can buy the private key though

Comment: Thanks! Where can I buy it, I can't find it on the webiste?

Comment: https://www.lightpollutionmap.info/help.html